# What does parentheses combined with underscore syntax mean in latest C# version?

Tags: c#

I saw sample code as below:

```cs
namespace CSharpNewFeature {

   record Product(string Name, decimal Price, bool IsFood);

   record Order(Product Product, int Quantity) {
      public decimal NetPrice => Product.Price * Quantity;
   }

   record Address(string Country);
   record UsAddress(string State) : Address("us");

   public static class VatStrategy {
      static decimal Vat(Address address, Order order)
         => address switch {
            UsAddress(var state) => Vat(RateByState(state), order),
            ("de") _ => DeVat(order),  // <--------?
            (var country) _ => Vat(RateByCountry(country), order), // <--------?
         };

      static decimal Vat_Prop(Address address, Order order)
         => address switch {
            { Country: "de" } => DeVat(order),
            { Country: var c } => Vat(RateByCountry(c), order),
         };

      static decimal RateByCountry(string country)
         => country switch {
            "it" => 0.22m,
            "jp" => 0.08m,
            _ => throw new ArgumentException($"Missing rate for {country}")
         };

      static decimal Vat(decimal rate, Order order)
         => order.NetPrice * rate;

      static decimal RateByState(string state)
         => state switch {
            "ca" => 0.1m,
            "ma" => 0.0625m,
            "ny" => 0.085m,
            _ => throw new ArgumentException($"Missing rate for {state}")
         };

      static decimal DeVat(Order order)
         => order.NetPrice * (order.Product.IsFood ? 0.08m : 0.2m);
   }
}
```

I don't understand how to interpret these two statments below:

```cs
("de") _ => DeVat(order),
(var country) _ => Vat(RateByCountry(country), order),
```

Especially `("de") _`, I know underscore mean "discard", but what are we discarding here? and what does `("de")` do here? What is the feature name of `(...) _` in latest C# specification?

Comment: The underscore is just a __variable name__, usually meant to have no meaning or be discarded.

Comment: The value in parenthesis is being used for pattern matching. And the result is being discarded.

Comment: The parenthesis is _deconstruction_ of the record, but I haven't figured out why you _need_ the underscore/a varaible to save to.

Comment: This is a combination of switch expression, record deconstruction and pattern matching. It's basically the same as `{ Country: "de" } => DeVat(order)`

Comment: It's an indicator that because you had a WTF moment and had to ask, it should be refactored into something understandable so another team member doesn't sit there going "WTF" next week

Comment: @CaiusJard Strong disagree, it's just modern syntax

Comment: @gunr2171 because if you don't have it, then `country` becomes an Address?

Comment: @slowjams what about `{ } addr => Vat(RateByCountry(addr.Country), order)` - does it make any sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple new(er) C# features being used here. The first is record [deconstructing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct) (sometimes also called "destructuring" in other languages) although it looks like the sample code is abridged because [records require two positional fields in order to automatically generate a deconstructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct#record-types).

```cs
record Widget(string Foo, string Bar);

var myWidget = new Widget("Hello", "World");

var (greeting, subject) = myAddress;

/* Prints "World". */
Console.WriteLine(subject);
```

Note that the type of the variables on the left side of the expression can be declared explicitly:

```cs
(string greeting, string _) = myAddress;

/* If the types match: */
string (greeting, _) = myWidget;
```

Or they can be inferred:

```cs
(var greeting, var _) = myWidget;

/* Or: */
var (greeting, _) = myWidget;
```

Or a mix of both:

```cs
(string greeting, var _) = myWidget;
```

---

The second feature being used is the [relational patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#relational-patterns) feature which is a new application of the traditional switch expression. The expression for the first pattern to match the input is executed and the rest are ignored. Here's a contrived example that returns a `string` based on the value of an `enum`. The discard is used like the `default` case; anything that reaches it will match.

```cs
enum Widget { Thing, Doodad, WhatsItCalled };

string WidgetIdentifier(Widget input) => 
    input switch {
        Widget.Thing => "You have a Thing! Lucky you!",
        Widget.Doodad => "You have a Doodad. That's not so bad.",
        _ => "You might have a Widget, but it's not worth much.";
    };

/* Prints "You have a Doodad! That's not so bad.". */
Console.WriteLine(WidgetIdentifier(Widget.Doodad));

/* Prints "You might have a Widget, but it's not worth much.". */
Console.WriteLine(WidgetIdentifier((Widget)12));
```

---

In your example, then:

```cs
static decimal Vat(Address address, Order order)
    => address switch {
        UsAddress(var state) => Vat(RateByState(state), order),
        ("de") _ => DeVat(order),  // <--------?
        (var country) _ => Vat(RateByCountry(country), order), // <--------?
    };
```

The switch is considering the `address` field which we know can be deconstructed. The patterns you asked about are:

- `("de")` which will match when the `Country` field of `address` is equal to `"de"`. The discard (`_`) is completely unnecessary since we don't use the value of `address` in the expression for this pattern. You can leave it out (e.g. `("de") => DeVat(order)`) and the statement would work the same. [See for yourself on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GSbQtl). Think of this case like "Deconstruct `address` and match it to the hypothetical deconstruction `("de")`".
- `(var country) _` which is both a pattern and a deconstruction to a variable. The discard means we're ignoring the value of `address` (and it can be omitted as in the first case), the `(var country)` deconstructs `address` so that `country` is equal to the value of the `Country` field on `address`. This will match any `Address` value. Think of this case like "Try to deconstruct `address` into `(var country)`. Even if it matches, you can ignore the result. (But since you've delcared a variable `country` in scope, it can still be used even though the match result was discarded)". Again, this is an odd way to write this since we know if `address` is not null, we can deconstruct it. Leaving out the discard would make that more clear in my mind.

Conversely, it might be more clear if we used explicit names for the results of a match:

```cs
static decimal Vat(Address address, Order order)
    => address switch {
        UsAddress(var state) => Vat(RateByState(state), order),
        ("de") germanAddress => DeVat(order),  // <--------?
        (var country) someAddress => Vat(RateByCountry(someAddress.Country), order), // <--------?
    };
```

See how `("de")` was used to match the case when `address` was in Germany, but we never used the `germanAddress` variable (which was identical to `address`)?

See how `(var country)` was used to match the case when `address` could be deconstructed? Here it's more obvious why you wouldn't always use a discard. We were able to access `someAddress.Country` (even though `country` contained the same value). This usage is unique in that there are two ways to access the value in `address.Country` - by deconstructing and using the result, or by matching and using the alias `someAddress.Country`.

Comment: @D M thank you for your answer. as you mentioned "records require two positional fields in order to automatically generate a deconstructor", but `Address` only has one positional field, so why it can still be deconstructed as `(var country)  _`  or `(var country) someAddress`?

Comment: That's an excellent question that I will have to look more into. I assumed the code sample was non-working, [and here's a sample that shows `Address` doesn't have a single-field deconstructor](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YqIxyf), but then [here's a sample showing the deconstructor in the pattern working](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ah48M2).